# How do I get rid of problem with tensorflow class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

I have a problem with tensorflow library.

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

So far I have only did this import and the error that I'm receiving is:

```
ValueError: operator __getitem__ cannot be overwritten again on class <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>.
```

Can anyone help me with this? I just want to add that I did pip install tensorflow.

Comment: Please can you provide the traceback for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please uninstall tensorflow and reinstall them as below

```
pip install tensorflow 

import tensorflow 
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```